# $http.post is sending empty data to RestApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using `AngularJS` in my application when i try to post the data to `RestAPI` it sends empty data

here is my Function of API

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string UpdateEmployee(Employees emp)
    {
using (_session = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession())
        {
            var query = _session.Load<Employees>(emp.Id);
            query.JobTitle = emp.JobTitle;
            query.Name = emp.Name;
            query.Owner = emp.Owner;
            query.Phone = emp.Phone;
            query.SearchedByName = emp.SearchedByName;
            query.CanLogin = emp.CanLogin;
            query.Gender = emp.Gender;
            query.About = emp.About;
            query.Email = emp.Email;
            _session.SaveChanges();
        }
        return emp.Id;
    }
```

AngularJS Code:

```
var updateEmployee = function(emp) {
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        var data = JSON.stringify(emp);
        console.log(emp);
        console.log(data);


   $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/Servicesapi/UpdateEmployee/',
          data: emp,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' }
            }).success(
                function() {
                    deffered.resolve();
                })
            .error(
                function() {
                    //Error
                    deffered.reject();
                });
        return deffered.promise;
    };
```

first `console.log(emp)` prints data but 2nd `console.log(data)` prints empty array `[]`

the `API` function is triggered when the above angular function executes but empty object of `Employees` is received.

**`console.log(emp)`**:

```
About: "hello this is about"
Bid: "businesses/129"
CanLogin: true
Email: "abc@yahoo.com"
Gender: "Male"
Id: "employees/193"
JobTitle: "Developer"
Name: "abc"
Owner: true
Phone: "+123456789"
SearchedByName: true
Service: Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: do you have JSON data in that emp? functions are not serialized to JSON. Can you show what is inside emp?

Comment: You have wrong content-type, if you send JSON it should be application/json.

Comment: changed the type still not working

Comment: if i change the type to `application/json` the object simply get's null while if th type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`then object is empty means all values of object contains null

Comment: Does your REST backend expect JSON?

Comment: The problem is that you have array instead of object (prototype should be Object), can you show where emp is defined or how updateEmployee is executed?

Comment: JSON.stringify don't like javascript array, just for test, add `emp.Service = {}` before the stringify and see if it is able to log some stringified json for you.

Comment: @WeTTTT JSON.stringify work fine with array, the problem that he have is that he has `emp = []; emp.About = "hello this is about";` instead of `emp = {}`

Comment: i first fetch a record then put it in `$scope.members` array update the values present in `$scope.members` and then pass it as a paramenter
so `$scope.members is emp`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I wanted JS code for updateEmployee. The problem is in JavaScript not on the server.

Comment: Show your $scope.members code and what is your record, how it's created.

Comment: @jcubic didnt get u
JS code is mentioned above

Comment: @jcubic see full Angular code here

http://plnkr.co/edit/XG5BcywagQ7gmdkgeB0d?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've created record as array and use it as object.

```
var record = [];
```

use

```
var record = {};
```

Comment: when to use [] and when to {}

Comment: @MohsinMustufa `[]` is new array, so if you have collection and want to add new element with `push()` you will use []. and if you add new elements like `foo.x = 10;` use `{}` which is new object.